# How do I fix openCV cvtColor error in my project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning

I am building handwriting recognition project but I am getting this error of `cvtColor` while trying to change the image from `BGR2HSV`.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
Lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])
Upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])
pred_class = 0
pts = deque(maxlen = 512)
blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
digit = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, Lower_blue, Upper_blue)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(mask, 15)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY +   cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
    center = None
    if len(cnts) >= 1:
        contour = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 250:
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
            cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, center, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)
            M = cv2.moments(contour)
            center = (int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00']))
            pts.appendleft(center)
            for i in range (1, len(pts)):
                if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                    continue
                cv2.line(blackboard, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (255, 255, 255), 10)
                cv2.line(img, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0,255), 5)
    elif len(cnts) == 0:
        if len(pts) != []:
            blackboard_gray = cv2.cvtColor(blackboard, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            blur1 = cv2.medianBlur(blackboard_gray, 15)
            blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur1, (5, 5), 0)
            thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            blackboard_cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
            if len(blackboard_cnts) >= 1:
                cnt = max(blackboard_cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
                print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
                if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 2000:
                    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                    digit = blackboard_gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    #new Image = process_letter(digit)
                    pred_probab, pred_class = keras_predict(model1, digit)
                    print(pred_class, pred_probab)

            pts = deque(maxlen = 512)
            blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype = uint8)
        cv2.putText(img, "Conv Network : " + str(letter_count    [pred_class]), (10, 470),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
        cv2.imshow("Contours", thresh)

        k = cv2.waitkey(10)
        if k == 27:
            break
```

How do I fix this issue of OpenCV error? Please help!

I am getting following error:

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11214: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == 0 || depth == 5) in function cv::cvtColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following error: `error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == 0 || depth == 5) in function cv::cvtColor` is because of camera unable to capture frame correctly. Check this by printing `ret` value. It camera is able to capture frame correctly, it will return `True`, else `False`. Above error is happening because `None` is passed to `cv2.cvtColor` function. You can use below code as a safety check:

```
if ret is True:
   # your code goes here
else:
   break
```

Moreover, please consider below points:

- It's `cv2.waitKey(10)`, not `cv2.waitkey(10)`[Capital 'K']
- `cv2.findContours` function return `3` values(i.e. image, contours and hierarchy) in `OpenCV 3.x` but just `2` values(i.e. contours, hierarchy) in `openCV 4.x`
- `len(pts) != []` doesn't make sense. Here, you are trying to compare a number to an empty list. Change it to `len(pts) != 0`.
- What's `letter_count` inside cv2.`putText` function. Kindly recheck it.
- In place of re-initializing deque(`pts = deque(maxlen = 512)`) in case of `len(cnts)==0` and `len(pts) != 0`, you can use the old `pts` by simply clearing it using `pts.clear()`. Just a thought!
- Also, add below code at the end:

  ```
  cap.release() 
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  ```

Try below modified code(Tested using `openCV v4.0.0`):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
Lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])
Upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])
pred_class = 0
pts = deque(maxlen = 512)
blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
digit = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype = np.uint8)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, Lower_blue, Upper_blue)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(mask, 15)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY +   cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    center = None
    if len(cnts) >= 1:
        contour = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 250:
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
            cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, center, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)
            M = cv2.moments(contour)
            center = (int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00']))
            pts.appendleft(center)
            # print(pts)
            for i in range (1, len(pts)):
                if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                    print("Continue")
                    continue
                cv2.line(blackboard, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (255, 255, 255), 10)
                cv2.line(img, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0,255), 5)
            cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
            cv2.imshow("Contours", thresh)

            # press q to stop
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    else:
        if len(pts) != 0:
            blackboard_gray = cv2.cvtColor(blackboard, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            blur1 = cv2.medianBlur(blackboard_gray, 15)
            blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur1, (5, 5), 0)
            thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            print('Hello')
            blackboard_cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
            if len(blackboard_cnts) >= 1:
                cnt = max(blackboard_cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
                print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
                if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 2000:
                    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                    digit = blackboard_gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    #new Image = process_letter(digit)
                    #pred_probab, pred_class = keras_predict(model1, digit)
                    print(digit.shape)

            #pts = deque(maxlen = 512)
            pts.clear()
            blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
            #cv2.putText(img, "Conv Network : " + str(letter_count[pred_class]), (10, 470), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, "Conv Network :", (10, 470), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
            cv2.imshow("Contours", thresh)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```